# Nested Pydantic Model return error with FastAPI : field required (type=value_error.missing)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I got a problem using [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) and [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/).
I try to return a list of records based on my Pydantic model.

Here is the SQLAlchemy Metadata :

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, JSON, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression

metadata = MetaData()

CustomLayers = Table(
    "custom_layers",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("data", JSON),
    Column("is_public", Boolean, default=expression.false()),
    Column("user_id", Integer),
)
```

Here is the "corresponding" pydantic model :

```py
from geojson_pydantic.features import FeatureCollection
from pydantic import BaseModel

class CustomLayerResponse(BaseModel):
    is_public: bool
    data: FeatureCollection
    user_id: int
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Here is my route :

```py
@router.get("/", response_model=List[CustomLayerResponse], status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def retrieve_by_user(user_id: int):
    layer_records = await customlayers_repository.retrieve_by_user_id(user_id)
    return layer_records
```

Here is the Retrieve operation using the [Databases library](https://www.encode.io/databases/) (SQL Alchemy based)

```py
async def retrieve_by_user_id(user_id: int):
    query = CustomLayersTable.select().where(user_id == CustomLayersTable.c.user_id)
    return await database.fetch_all(query=query)
```

But when I run this I got bunches of `ValidationError` from pydantic saying that :

```py
response -> 7 -> id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 7 -> user_id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 7 -> is_public
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 7 -> data
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

But what is really strange is that if I loop through the DB records returned by the ORM and manually create instances of the pydantic schema in this way :

```py
@router.get("/", response_model=List[CustomLayerResponse], status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def retrieve_by_user(user_id: int):
    layer_records = await customlayers_repository.retrieve_by_user_id(user_id)
    response = []
    for l in layer_records:
        manual_instance = CustomLayerResponse(data=FeatureCollection.parse_raw(l.get("data")),
                                user_id=l.get("user_id"),
                                id=l.get("id"),
                                is_public=l.get("is_public"))
        response.append(manual_instance)
    return response
```

Then everything works just as expected and I got the List of `CustomLayerResponse` in response.

So I wonder what could be the problem with the "auto" validation from pydantic model (the one provided by the `response_model` parameter provided by FastAPI, that I set here as `List[CustomLayerResponse]`) ?

Comment: @SuperShoot. Thanks for your comment. Actually the orm_mode is required here to read the data from the ORM model and not only from a dict as specified here in the doc : https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/?h=orm_mode#use-pydantics-orm_mode But I had to do it manually because even if it should work automatically it does not and this is my question

Comment: @SuperShoot Well. Thank you. You right. I removed the orm_mode and it begins to work for simple fields...but not for my nested model (i.e : `data : FeatureCollection` which is an imported pydantic model from the `geojson_pydantic` library)....The error I got in this case is `value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)`. But if I remove this field from the CustomLayerResponse pydantic model, then it works like a charm with other fileds of value  types

Comment: @SuperShoot I suppose that I need a deserialization somehow but I cannot face out how to perform it in the best way...it should be a use case for nested pydantic model but I did not find one in the doc

Comment: @SuperShoot I use postgresql. I guess I need to use the `parse_raw()` but without instanciate the model manually as I did, I cannot face out how to do ? Maybe it's not possible...and in case of nested model we have to loop manually and deserialize...but it sound weird that pydantic and fastapi both did not handle this case...

Comment: asyncpg loads `json` and `jsonb` as `str` ([ref](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html?highlight=json#type-conversion)). I found [this](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html#example-automatic-json-conversion), but not sure how you can apply that via sqlalchemy. [aiopg converts to dict by default](https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core.html?highlight=json#json), but that doesn't seem to be supported by `databases`.

Comment: seems that some do use `aiopg` with `databases`, but not without issue: https://github.com/encode/databases/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+aiopg

Comment: A problem could be due to the fact that the model cannot be convert to dictionary and thus the model will miss the input parameters

Answer (score -2):

You data field should use a class that extends both FeatureCollection and BaseModel so that you can set its Config subclass field orm_true to true as well.

I haven't tested this with FeatureCollection it self but something similar happened to me.